# css opacity - internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opacity

i'm working with opacity today and from some reason it wont work on internet explorer

here is my CSS :

```
.box_1{opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)};
.box_1:hover{opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<div class="box_1">
    <img src="abc.png"/>
</div>
```

the HOVER div does not work.
what is the problem here?

Comment: What *exactly* doesn't work? The `opacity=100` or the whole thing?

Comment: @Pekka: the hover one with the 100 opacity

Comment: Do you have `DOCTYPE` declared properly in your test page? Without it, IE will cause all kinds of weird problems..

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you give me the right doctype?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a curly bracket at the end of your first line, it should be:

```
.box_1{opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);}
.box_1:hover{opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
```

Also if you're using IE6 the `:hover` selector won't work on anything except `<a>` tags. To get around it you'll need to use something like [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html).

Comment: i just copy it with 1 missing char. the problem still remain.

Comment: Ah ok, check the answer again I've added a note about IE6 in case that's the problem

Comment: I've just tried [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKwBV/) in IE9 and it works fine for me, are you able to share a link to the page you're having problems on?

Comment: yeah , i tried it too on jsfriddle and it work fine , try to open it on localhost and see the problem , that's weird.

Comment: Could it be that you've got another element (either absolutely positioned or floated) somehow overlapping the `<div>` or `<img>` tags? In that case the hover event wouldn't fire