# Changing Visibility of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the visibility of HTML elements except some particular elements. I want the elements to be at the same positions and alignments and just the visibility of elements to be changed. Can somebody please help me doing that?

I tried doing the same using jquery by seeing the answer to [How to hide all elements except one using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535331/how-to-hide-all-elements-except-one-using-jquery) but this changes the positions and alignments of elements.

```
$('body > :not(#averageCustomerReviews)').hide(); //this hid everything
$('#averageCustomerReviews').appendTo('body'); //but this changed the position
```

I currently have locators to elements like xpaths/CSS Selectors which I don't want to hide.

For e.g. I have this [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439358078). And I want to view only [image] at the place it is right now by hiding all other elements.

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` Is what you're looking for

Comment: You can also use `opacity` to change the visibility of the elements.

Comment: Please include the HTML you are using.

Comment: Please do not include links, but rather your actual code. This insures that future readers will understand the context of the question.

Comment: @gibberish Could you please provide the link?

Comment: Here are a few examples of using the opacity css method: [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp), [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386714/css3-cross-browser-opacity), [another SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546555/css-opacity-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 5):

**VISIBILITY USAGE**

jQuery

```
$("#element").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

CSS

```
#element {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you want all the others elements than `#element` to be "invisible":

jQuery

```
$(":not(#element)").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

CSS

```
:not(#element) { 
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**ANSWERING YOUR 'AFTER' QUESTION - LET ALL INVISIBLE EXCEPT ONE**

If you can't assign an 'invisible' class to the elements that should be invisibile (best solution), you can render visible only one child element in this manner, see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damoiser/YPcq8/1/).

That mean:

- set all 'invisible': `$("*").css("visibility", "hidden");`
- set visible the element you want to show: `$("#element").css("visibility", "visible");`

In your case the element you would like to show is a little 'nested' and you can do in this manner:

```
  // set all 'invisible'
  $("*").css("visibility", "hidden");

  // set visible the element with their 'sub-child'
  $("#averageCustomerReviews_feature_div, #averageCustomerReviews, #averageCustomerReviews a, .reviewCountTextLinkedHistogram, .reviewCountTextLinkedHistogram a, .a-popover-trigger, .a-popover-trigger i").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Not nice, but it works.
[image: Screenshot]

With a html tree complex like this one and without any possibility to assign some custom class. I think that this is the only solution...

Comment: I want all the other elements than `#element` to be hidden.

Comment: But it also hides `#element`. Is it because it is nested under other divs?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal can be, maybe there is a parent div that is affected to the "invisibility", then the child is affected too

Comment: So, how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal I think that the better way to do this is to assign a class to all the elements that should have the visibility: hidden. Then you can call it with one of the example above.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal Without seeing your markup, we'd have no way to tell you exactly how to do this. What damoiser suggested about assigning a class to all of the elements that should be hidden is probably your best bet.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal re-re-updated with a working solution (tested)

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility: hidden;`. Unlike `display: none;` the element will still be there.

Too apply to all elements except one use a style like this:

```
* {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#element {
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8z2b/)

[Information on visibility.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to hide everything but `#element` then use this:

```
:not(#element) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See here for more info on the `:not()` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

**UPDATE**

You can also chain `:not()` selectors together to exclude multiple elements. For example, if you have `#element1` and `#element2` that should not be hidden from view, then do something like this:

```
:not(#element1):not(#element2) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up in CSS, where `class` is the class that's on all the elements you want to hide:

```
.class {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

and then

```
$('#element').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

jquery

```
 $("#elementid").onclick(function() {
  $('body').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
    $('#elementid').css({ 'visibility': 'visible'});
});
```